# Is it possible to set http headers from SSI?

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, litespeed, server-side-includes

I have this configuration for static html pages, where redirects are done from flat files as well:

*old-location.html*

```
<!-- {new-location.html} -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting to new location</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="new-location.html" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='new-location.html'" /></noscript>
<script>window.location = "new-location.html"</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="new-location.html">[old-location.html moved here]</a>
</body>
```

The html is supposed to only serve as a graceful chain of fallbacks, while the comment on the first line is a configuration hook for proper `http` redirects that, since there's no runtime environment, need to be done by the webserver.

Currently I do this in Openresty, with Lua's matching patterns, finding the new-location and then setting it as a 301 redirect.

```
header_filter_by_lua_block { 
local address = ngx.var.document_root .. ngx.var.document_uri
local file = io.open(address, "rb")
local content = file:read(100)
file:close()
local location = string.match(content, "{(%g+)}")
ngx.header['location'] = location
ngx.status = 301
}
-- ideally I should intercept the response body and spare the extra file read, but it seems that even with Lua this is not possible
```

However, not everybody accepts to switch to a new webserver. So I wonder if there's a way to do it with off-the-shelf Nginx or, even better, with a generic method that's supported by most/all webservers.

Since the *server side includes* (is there a way to retrieve a ssi variable from the file and set it as header?) and the *sub_module* (replace anything except the needed part with some regex, maybe?) both do parse the entire body already, I thought there might be a way, but I don't quite know where to start looking.

Comment: If you're using JS, you should be able to parse the html tag you need. What are you trying to parse and I can give you a regex ?

Comment: JS is of no use as the headers are already sent (unless I use nginx's njs, which wouldn't be much better than now). The matching pattern above – "{(%g+)}" – is good enough, only problem being that it requires a quite rare flavour of a webserver.

Comment: I wish I could help you but my expertise is in regular expressions. I have large experience with html/xml/sgml parsing, but it looks like you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to set HTTP headers from SSI, but you could use a CGI program to do this.

Comment: Never worked with CGI... how'd that do it exactly? Could it actually send headers back through the webserver instead of the required html document? Will it run as a separate process? Would it be decently secure?